# problems with angular version and promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I don't realize why this code works fine with angularjs 1.2.0-rc.2 but not with later version (I tried with 1.2.0, 1.4.9, 1.5.7)

**index.html**

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
  <h1>Open Pull Requests for Angular JS</h1>
  <ul ng-controller="DashboardCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="pullRequest in pullRequests">
      {{ pullRequest.title }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
  <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.js"></script>-->
  <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>-->
  <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>-->
  <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

**scripts/app.js**

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

app.controller('DashboardCtrl', ['$scope', 'GithubService',function($scope, GithubService) {
    $scope.pullRequests = GithubService.getPullRequests();
}]);

app.factory('GithubFactory', ['$q', '$http',function($q, $http) {
    var myFactory = {};
    myFactory.getPullRequests = function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get('https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular.js/pulls')
            .success(function(data) {
            deferred.resolve(data); // Success
            })
            .error(function(reason) {
            deferred.reject(reason); // Error
            });

        return deferred.promise;
    }

    return myFactory;

}]);
```

debugging I can see that the promise is resolved, but the data are not displayed...
What's the right way to use the promises?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because since 1.2 promises are not automatically "unfolded" in templates. You need to set resolved data explicitly:

This is incorrect:

```
$scope.pullRequests = GithubService.getPullRequests();
```

And should be:

```
GithubService.getPullRequests().then(function(data) {
    $scope.pullRequests = data;
});
```

And one more thing. You should not construct promises with `deferred` object because `$http` service already returns one for you:

```
app.factory('GithubFactory', ['$http', function($http) {
    var myFactory = {};
    myFactory.getPullRequests = function() {
        return $http.get('https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular.js/pulls')
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.data;
            });
    };
    return myFactory;
}]);
```

Comment: Yep! Promise auto-unwrap has been deprecated since 1.2.0-rc.3 read more at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#angular-expression-parsing-parse-interpolate-